# How is the OpenGL pipeline executed specifically?

Tags: opengl

I am looking for clarification on the order execution in the opengl pipeline. I have two scenarios. Which one is correct? Or if neither what is?

Standard opengl pipeline: Vertex shader->Primitive assembly->Geometry shader (optional)->Rasterization->Fragment shader->Tests and Blending

Scenario #1: (Parallel-Parallel)
One gpu core (or a few) process a primitive (3 vertices) from start to finish (vertex->assemble->Raster->Fragment->Blending) while other cores work on other primitives from start to finish (the whole pipeline in parallel).

Scenario #2: (Series-Parallel)
All the cores use the vertex shader to process all the vertices, then stores the data in a buffer. Then all the cores assemble primitives from that buffer and put them in buffer. Then same for raster. Then same for Fragment. Then Blending into final framebuffer. (One shader at a time across all cores and buffer data in between)

I am hoping scenario #1 is correct because memory space is critical in my application and scenario #2 seems like is would use a lot more memory.

Comment: Impossible to tell. OpenGL doesn't specify anything in that regard, which means that different GPUs (or even different driver versions) might have different behaviour.

Comment: Also note, that the two scenarios are not the only possible ones. For example, a number of core might run the vertex shader on all vertices. But when the first primitive is finished, another group of core can already start to execute the next pipeline stage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like most graphics API, OpenGL represents an abstraction of any particular hardware mechanics of rendering something. The purpose of that is so that you can code to the abstraction without *caring* about the particular hardware your code is executing on.

So by definition, OpenGL cannot dictate the fundamentals of how a GPU does its work.

And there is variance in how GPUs from different vendors operate. You largely shouldn't care about that, as with a few exceptions, those details will not matter to your application's overall performance.

If a GPU is going to transform all of your vertices, store them in a buffer, and process them later... it's doing that for a reason. It is *designed* to work that way, and you don't get to change it.